# PHP Parse error - unexpected T_STRING

Tags: xml, php

In Windows (WAMP) I have an index.php like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?php
    // ...
?>
```

and it works as expected.
Now I've just configured a LAMP on Ubuntu and the same file (when invoked from a browser) gives me an error. Looking in `error.log` I've found

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /var/www/test/index.php on line 1

If I remove first line everything works fine.
What's wrong? Why this works on Windows and not on Linux?
Could this be caused from a particular extension?

Comment: I think the short tags answers will work; in my experience, I've always echoed the `<?xml ... ?>` string from PHP code so I didn't have to worry about how short tags were set.

Comment: echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';

Comment: This also happens if you try and run `phpunit` and don't complete a parameter. For example `phpunit --filter -c phpunit.xml` would trigger this same error.

Comment: just echo question mark as string. <{{"?"}}xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"{{"?"}}>

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It sounds like you have short tags enabled, which will cause PHP to try and parse what comes after `<?`.

Set the config option [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) in php.ini to `0` or `Off` and restart Apache.

Comment: A silly mistake that took me a lot of time: thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea to work with XML as a string.

You should use php XML libraries like http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if short tags are enabled/disabled on php.ini?