# Unable to parse XML using Jquery's $.parseXML

Tags: jquery, xml, parsexml

I have a xml which is generated by BPMN.
It has the below code with xml tag when it is getting generated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn2:defvar 
    xmlDoc = $.parseXMLinitions 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:bpmn2="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" 
    xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" 
    xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" 
    xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" id="sample-diagram" 
    targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL BPMN20.xsd">
    <!-- ......so on-->
</bpmn2:defvar>
```

So when i use `$.parseXML` to parse it, it shows error at version like

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected `version` (T_STRING) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/1234.php on line 4
```

How can i resolve this ?

Comment: Have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10506100) - do you have php short tags turned on ? (This flag interferes with the xml prologue as it makes php parse _everything_ starting with `<?` ( not just `<?php` ))

Answer (score 0):

The code excerpt you've presented is malformed - the jQuery function call has found it's way into the xml body.

The following is parsed without problems:

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn2:defvar
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:bpmn2="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
    xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI"
    xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC"
    xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" id="sample-diagram"
    targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL BPMN20.xsd">
    <!-- ......so on-->
</bpmn2:defvar>`);
```

The error message suggests you may have an issue with php generating the embedding page, specifically the `short_open_tag` being set in `php.ini` - see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10506100).

Comment: But i'm directly running it without using any server.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Ok. What makes the (php) error message in your question appear?